# vimscript syntax not pattern

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have this vimscript:

```
syn region      fdocCommand     start="^@" end="$" contained 
syn region      fdocComment     start="^@" end="^@tangle " contains=fdocCommand keepend
" syn region      fdocComment     start="^@" end="^@felix" contains=fdocCommand keepend
```

but what i need is the region defined by: `start="^@"` followed by anything except `"tangle"` or `"felix"` and ended by either `"@tangle"` or `"@felix"`. A weaker form would actually do, either the `@tangle` line above OR the commented out `@felix` line.

The actual use is a literate programming tool with `@commands` like `@h1` heading, `@title`, etc, and code is introduced by `@felix` or `@tangle` and ended by the next `@command`. As it happens my webserver can display this with syntax highlighting and hyperlinking, and the real set of code commands include `@python`, `@ocaml`, `@c++` etc. For Felix, the `@..@felix` sequence is actually recognised by the compiler as a comment, so the literate code can be compiled directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a region only with `@commands` that are not `@tangle`, you need *negative lookahead* via `\@!`:
`^@\%(tangle\)\@!`. To ensure that it's really only `tangle`, not something *starting with* `tangle`, you need an additional `$` assertion; and to not match `felix`, too, another branch: `^@\%(\%(tangle\|felix\)$\)\@!`

So, this should do:

```
syn region      fdocComment     start="^@\%(\%(tangle\|felix\)$\)\@!" end="^@\%(tangle\|felix\)$" contains=fdocCommand keepend
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work: syn region      fdocComment     start="^@\%(\%(tangle \|felix\)\)\@!" end="^@\%(tangle \|felix\)" contains=fdocCommand keepend.